# no function clause matching in Enum.reduce/3

Tags: enums, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm getting this error when trying to sum a list I'm getting back from a comprehension:

```
range = 1..999

multiple_of_3_or_5? = fn(n) -> (rem(n, 3) == 0 || rem(n, 5) == 0) end
IO.inspect for n <- range, multiple_of_3_or_5?.(n),
  do: Enum.reduce n, 0, fn(x) -> x end

#=> ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Enum.reduce/3
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712655/protocol-undefinederror-protocol-enumerable-not-implemented-for-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in the third parameter of `Enum.reduce` needs to have two parameters, the element from the enumerable and an accumulator. You currently only have one parameter, `x`.

Answer (score 0):

The first and third param are wrong. You can try this

```
range = 1..999
multiple_of_3_or_5? = fn(n) -> (rem(n, 3) == 0 || rem(n, 5) == 0) end
for n <- range, multiple_of_3_or_5?.(n) do n end |> Enum.reduce(0, 
fn(x, acc) -> x + acc end)
```

**or**

```
range = 1..999
multiple_of_3_or_5? = fn(n) -> (rem(n, 3) == 0 || rem(n, 5) == 0) end
Enum.reduce_while(range, 0, fn i, acc ->
  if multiple_of_3_or_5?.(i), do: {:cont, acc + i}, else: {:cont, acc}
end)
```